# WPF - Resaltar un objeto con un borde rojo

Tags: wpf, color

Estoy comenzando a trastear con los proyectos de WPF y estoy bastante atascada con una tontería que no encuentro cómo hacer. He creado una primera pantalla con tres combobox y un botón. Al clicar el botón quiero hacer la comprobación de si en el último combobox no se ha seleccionado nada y, en caso de que no, resaltar con un borde en rojo el tercer combobox.

El XAML es el siguiente:

```
    <Grid x:Name="GRD_BackgroundStart" Background="LightGray">
    <Border MinWidth="400" MinHeight="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Padding="10" CornerRadius="15" Background="WhiteSmoke">
        <StackPanel Width="auto" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="0, 10, 0, 10" Background="WhiteSmoke">
            <Label x:Name="LBL_SelectEntorno" Content="Selecciona el tipo de entorno con el que quieres trabajar" Margin="0, 50, 0, 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="CB_Entorno" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" DropDownClosed="CB_Entorno_DropDownClosed">
                <ComboBoxItem Name="cbiPRO">PRODUCCIÓN</ComboBoxItem>
                <ComboBoxItem Name="cbiPRE">PREPRODUCCIÓN</ComboBoxItem>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label x:Name="LBL_SelectPartner" Content="Selecciona el partner con el que quieres trabajar" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="309" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="CB_Partner" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300" DropDownClosed="CB_Partner_DropDownClosed">
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbiPartner1" Content="Partner1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem x:Name="cbiPartner2" Content="Partner2"/>
            </ComboBox>
            <Label x:Name="LBL_SelectCustomerKey" Content="Selecciona el cliente con el que quieres trabajar" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="372" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center"/>
            <ComboBox x:Name="CB_CustomerKey" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300">
            </ComboBox>
            <Button x:Name="BTN_Start" Margin="0, 0, 0, 15" Content="ENTRAR" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="BTN_Start_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Border>
</Grid>
```

Y el intento que he hecho (y que no ha funcionado):

```
        private void BTN_Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if(CB_CustomerKey.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {                
            CB_CustomerKey.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
            CB_CustomerKey.BorderThickness = new Thickness(3);
        }            
    }
```

El ancho del borde sí que se modifica, pero no hay manera de ver el color.

¡Gracias de antemano!

Comment: Me temo que para cambiar el color del borde de un `ComboBox` tendrás que acceder a su template y modificarlo. Te recomendaría algo mucho mas sencillo: mete tu combobox en un `Border` y modifica el color de este en lugar del propio del `Combobox`. Otra opción es que uses la validación de datos que ya tiene WPF, creo recordar que en ese caso lo haría por ti, puedes mirar por ejemplo [esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20509923/579895)

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Lo he conseguido añadiendo un Border tal y como indicabas :)

Comment: Me alegra mucho haberte ayudado. Considera añadir una respuesta explicando como lo has solucionado y el código resultante, de esa manera podrás ayudar a otros que tengan tu misma duda. Pasadas 48 horas podrás incluso aceptar tu propia respuesta si no hay otra que te haya ayudado mas. Un saludo y Bienvenida a [es.so]

Comment: Vaya, veo que ta adelantaste a mi comentario :) Pero en el sitio la forma adecuada es poner la solución en una respuesta, no editar la pregunta. De esa manera es más sencillo localizar la misma. Si no te importa, pon la respuesta en la parte inferior donde pone "Tu Respuesta"

Comment: No sabía cómo iba, normalmente siempre he visto a la gente editar con la solución. Ya está la respuesta añadida, muchas gracias por la pequeña guía ;)

Comment: Si, este sitio es diferente porque no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Aqui estamos para ayudar en lo posible, cualquier duda que tengas puedes preguntarnos. Un saludo y bienvenida :)

Answer (score 3):

Lo he conseguido añadiendo el combobox a un Border.

XAML:

```
<Border x:Name="BRD_CustomerKey" Background="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="center" Padding="1" >
    <ComboBox x:Name="CB_CustomerKey" Margin="0, 0, 0, 0" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="300"/>
</Border>
```

Botón:

```
private void BTN_Start_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {            
        if(CB_CustomerKey.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            // do something
        }
        else
        {
            BRD_CustomerKey.Background = Brushes.Red; 
        }            
    }
```

Comment: Hola @Sanski una solución orientada a ofrecer "uso general" podría usar una clase 'error', de modo que se use contenedores transparentes para los elementos a validar y, aquellos que no pasen la validación reciban dicha clase y su estilo aplique el efecto deseado.